# what is the best way to write error's log file on Windows-mobile?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

what is the best way to write error's log file on Windows-mobile ?

i need any C# sample code for this

thank's in advance

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the **EventLog** class of the **OpenNETCF.Diagnostics** namespace of the [Smart Device Framework](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx) to do this. I prefer using the Smart Device Framework simply because the classes often try to mirror the names and functionality of their counterparts from the full .NET framework as closely as possible, plus the community edition is free :)

Documentation for the Smart Device Framework is [here](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/).